# Kendo Grid: Delete button without X icon

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to display Delete button without X Icon in kendo grid. Is there any way to do it ?
Note: I am using Kendo MVC GRID.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<RxConnectEntities.DeleteFileDTO>().Name("deleteList")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.DeleteFaxID).Hidden(true);
        columns.Bound(p => p.FaxName).Width(100).Title("File Name");
        columns.Bound(p => p.PerformedDateTime).Width(75).Title("Archive Date").Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
        columns.Command(command => { command.Destroy().Text("Move"); }).Width(50);
        columns.Bound(p => p.FilePath).Hidden(true);
    })
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine).DisplayDeleteConfirmation("Are you sure want to Move this Finance File?"))
    .Pageable(p => p.PageSizes(true))
        .Scrollable()
        .Sortable()
        .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single).Type(GridSelectionType.Row))
        .Events(events => events.Change("onChange"))
        .Groupable()
    .Filterable(filterable => filterable.Extra(false).Operators(operators => operators.ForString(str => str.Clear().StartsWith("Starts with").Contains("contains").IsEqualTo("Is equal to"))))
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:738px;" })
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax().ServerOperation(true)
        .PageSize(20)
        .Model(m => m.Id(p => p.DeleteFileID))
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetFileList", "Fax"))
    .Destroy(update => update.Action("MoveFileFromArchiveToQueue", "Operation"))
        ))
```

Here is my code. But I don't know from where I have option to remove Delete Icon(X)

Comment: What's your current code? What did you try? Why didn't it work? What do you think the problem is?

Comment: @bjb568, I am not finding anyway to remove X symbol by kendo grid options.

Comment: So did you try fixing it yourself somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was searching for if any direct command for removing x symbol. But I didnt find anyway. So i tried to see grid html code in firebug and I found there is a span for the icon which has **two class "k-icon" and "k-delete"**. k-icon class is used for other icon also like filter or edit. and k-delete is only for delete icon so I tried following and it works:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  var grid = $('#deleteList').data("kendoGrid");
  grid.bind('dataBound', function (e) {
    this.element.find('.k-delete').remove();
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What did you do wrong? What does this solve? How? Please read [how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).

Comment: I prefer to do the same, but without JS. Because it's a SPA app and contents are being dynamically loaded. Any CSS solution?

Answer (score 2):

I solved with the following (in 2018):

```
columns.Command(command => { command.Destroy().Text("Move").IconClass("k-no-icon"); }).Width(50);
```

IconClass does not matter, you can choose anything that is different from "k-icon"

Answer (score 0):

This approach seems like a bit of a hack. Ideally, the answer for the OP would be around how to template the markup generated by the Grid's command type columns. I'm not sure how to do that myself, but can answer this with a CSS only solution.

You could use the display property to control visibility of the element containing the icon and essentially hide it. Using the table from the OP as example...

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<RxConnectEntities.DeleteFileDTO>().Name("deleteList")...
```

You could use CSS to write a rule like...

```
#deleteList .k-delete { display: none; }
```